# couchbase add subdocument unique array values

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have a couchbase document as

```
{
    "last": 123,
    "data": [
        [0, 1.1],
        [1, 2.3]
    ]
}
```

currently have code to upsert the document to change the last property and add values to the data array, however, cannot find a way to insert unique values only. I'd like to avoid fetching the whole document and doing the filtering in javascript. Is there any way in couchbase? 
arrayAddUnique will fail, cause there are floats in the subarrays per couchbase docs.

```
.mutateIn(`document`)
          .upsert("last", 234)
          .arrayAppend("data", newDataArray)
          .execute( ... )
```

Comment: Would it be possible to store those numbers as strings instead of floats as a workaround?

Comment: yes, it would be possible. not the best solution but a nice idea, thanks.